# Можно ли как-то равно распределить нагрузку на потоки?

Tags: linux, debian

На ноутбуке стоит Debian 9 и мне надо как-нибудь распределять нагрузку во время запуска приложений, чтоб один поток не захлебывался на 100%, а нагрузка равно распределялась между всеми потоками :?

Answer (score 4):

Если коротко, то нет.

Приложение которое запускается обычно использует один поток и он будет загружать одно ядро. Так уж его написали программисты.

Если распределить его по потокам, то оно загрузит все ядра, а не каждое по половинке, если не упрется в диск. Но диски медленные, даже ссд и поэтому в скорости запуска не выйграешь.

Если переживаете что приложение молотит одно ядро, то посмотрите подольше. Линукс его перекинет на другое через некоторое время, чтоб схема грелась равномерно. Перекидывать чаще нет смысла.